# Synchronous calling web API service for a generic method

Tags: restkit, restkit-0.20

I am using RestKit version 0.20.3 to make a generic method that is used in many other places.  The problem is the returned value from that method is always nil because the "return location;" statement is executed BEFORE the Success call back function over the [objectManager getObjectsAtPath ...] method (see below codes).

I want the "return location;" statement must WAIT for the block variable "location" is filled with data from the Success call back function inside the [objectManager getObjectsAtPath ...] method.  How can I do this?

Thank you for your help.

My generic method looks like:

```
-(KNSunGoogleLatitudeLongitudeGeometryLocation*)getSynchronouslyLatitudeLongitudeWithAddress:(NSString*)address
{
    __block KNSunGoogleLatitudeLongitudeGeometryLocation* location = [[KNSunGoogleLatitudeLongitudeGeometryLocation alloc] init];


    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api"];
    AFHTTPClient * client = [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:baseURL];
    [client setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:RKMIMETypeJSON];
    RKObjectManager *objectManager = [[RKObjectManager alloc] initWithHTTPClient:client];


    //1. KNSunGoogleLatitudeLongitudeGeometryLocation

    RKObjectMapping *locationMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[KNSunGoogleLatitudeLongitudeGeometryLocation class]];
    [locationMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"lat", @"lng"]];


    //2. KNSunGoogleLatitudeLongitudeGeometry

    RKObjectMapping *geometryMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[KNSunGoogleLatitudeLongitudeGeometry class]];

    //3. KNSunGoogleLatitudeLongitude

    RKObjectMapping *latLongMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[KNSunGoogleLatitudeLongitude class]];



    //4. property/relationship mapping

    [geometryMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping
                                         relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"location"
                                         toKeyPath:@"location"
                                         withMapping:locationMapping]];

    [latLongMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping
                                        relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"geometry"
                                        toKeyPath:@"geometry"
                                        withMapping:geometryMapping]];



    // 6. response
    RKResponseDescriptor * responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:latLongMapping
                                                                                             method:RKRequestMethodGET
                                                                                        pathPattern:nil
                                                                                            keyPath:@"results"
                                                                                        statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
    // 7
    [objectManager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];



    NSDictionary *queryParams;
    queryParams = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:address, @"address", @"false", @"sensor", nil];


    // 6

    [objectManager getObjectsAtPath:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json"
                         parameters:queryParams
                            success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation * operaton, RKMappingResult *mappingResult)
     {

             //-----------
             NSArray* results = [mappingResult array];
             KNSunGoogleLatitudeLongitude* result0 = [results objectAtIndex:0];
             KNSunGoogleLatitudeLongitudeGeometry* geometry = result0.geometry;

             location= geometry.location;

             NSLog(@"lat=%@, long=%@", location.lat, location.lng);


     }
                            failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation * operaton, NSError * error)
     {
         NSLog (@"failure: operation: %@ \n\nerror: %@", operaton, error);
     }];


    return location;  // note: ALWAYS RETURNs nil 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change what you want because it's a bad design. You should not block the requestor while the request is in progress. Instead you should pass a block to your general method that is executed from the block you pass to RestKit. This allows you to properly respect the asynchronous nature of the request.

If you did want to proceed with blocking, you could use look at using a semaphore. But, you would need to manage this yourself. And you wouldn't be able to trigger the request on the main thread - ever. These are significant hurdles to general usage and will probably cause you issues in the future.

Comment: Thank you. I make another block parameter to my existing general method. So, any codes that call the general method need to pass in a block to be executed at the call-back success function of RestKit in the general method.